# Specifying desired packages for Gradle Javadoc task

Tags: ant, migration, gradle, javadoc

I'm trying to convert an ant build file to Gradle and I was wondering if there exists a way to specify which packages should be in the javadoc in the same way 'packagenames' works in ant?

Thanks 
Jonathan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the ['includes'/'excludes' properties](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc:excludes), or related methods. The patterns use the same syntax as ant.

```
javadoc {
    exclude "**/internal/**"
}
```

As another example, if the build process generates Java source files into a build directory, the Javadocs can be generated using:

```
javadoc {
  source = "$buildDir/"
  include( "**/*.java" )
}
```

This ensures that only `.java` files are parsed. Note that the parentheses are optional.