# How to override explicitly defined Java source files for Javadoc using additional options files?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have some tool creating an options file for Javadoc containing lots of individual Java source files to process. That tool simply adds all Java files automatically and allows me to add additional options files to the process created manually. The goal is to use such an additional options file to make Javadoc ignore some of the explicitly defined source files.

The first automatically generated options file looks like the following:

```
-classpath '[...]'
-d '[...]'
-doctitle '[...]'
'C:\\Users\\[...]\\package-info.java'
'C:\\Users\\[...]\\[...].java'
[...]
```

It contains a lot more paths for each individual Java-file in my project of course. The tools then invokes Javadoc the following way, where all but the first options file is the one I have control over:

```
javadoc @optsFile1 @optsFile2 @optsFile3
```

**So, is it possible at all to somehow override the explicit paths of the first file using some options in the later files only?**

I already tried various combinations of `-exclude` and `-subpackages`, but none of them worked. Javadoc always seems to process the explicitly defined files of the first and as well outputs their HTML. I don't care about unnecessary processing those files as well, I only don't want all of their HTML in the output folder. Would be great to have some option to post-filter things based on package names, because I would like to avoid to deal with paths.

Thanks!

Comment: What tool are you using, and tell me if you are using Spring

Comment: I'm using Gradle, but that shouldn't matter, my question is for a general approach by using options files only. I'm aware already of different Gradle-specific workarounds for my problem, like the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401982/specifying-desired-packages-for-gradle-javadoc-task

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning What do you mean by explicitly defined files? Please [edit] your question to show an example of java filenames, how you run the `javadoc` application (with which arguments) and what the result currently is, but what the result should be instead. Also explain how your "options files" are working and what they contain (are you talking about the `@files` argument?).

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning Why do you specify the files explicitly if you actually don't want them? Why do you not work on packages instead so you can use `-exclude`? The `javadoc` application can work with classnames and packages instead, you don't need to provide java source code files explicitly.

Comment: @Progman I don't define those files explicitly, the tool does that automatically and like can be read, `-exclude` doesn't seem to work in this scenario. It seems to only work in combination of `-sourcepath` and/or `-subpackages`.

Comment: Note to self: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467118/how-to-override-options-like-notimestamp-using-additional-options-files-for-j?noredirect=1&lq=1