# How to override options like `-notimestamp` using additional options files for Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have some tool executing Javadoc with an automatically generated options file, which contain options like `-notimestamp` to disable various features of Javadoc. That tool only allows me to add additional options files during processing to get a command line like the following:

```
javadoc @optsFile1 @optsFile2 @optsFile3
```

**Is there any way to re-enable some of the `-no*`-options using some later options file?**

Something easy like `-notimestamp=false` doesn't work and I don't see any `yes`-like options corresponding to the `no`-ones in the docs. So I think it's not possible without actually removing `-notimestamp` and prevent it from being set at all. Correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Note to self: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464503/how-to-override-explicitly-defined-java-source-files-for-javadoc-using-additiona